# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC error CS1061 does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I attached the context for the model and controller.  I couldn't get why I got this error:

> CS1061 does not contain a definition for

This is the `DbContext`:

```
    public virtual DbSet<Eng_Designation_Name> Eng_Designation_Name { get; set; }

    modelBuilder.Entity<Eng_Designation_Name>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Designation_Names_Id);

        entity.ToTable("Eng_Designation_Name");

        entity.Property(e => e.Designation_Names_Id)
              .HasColumnName("Designation_Names_Id");

        entity.Property(e => e.Designation_Names)
              .HasMaxLength(250)
              .IsUnicode(false)
              .HasColumnName("Designation_Names");

        entity.Property(e => e.AddDate)
              .HasColumnType("datetime")
              .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

       entity.Property(e => e.AddBy)
             .HasMaxLength(250)
             .IsUnicode(false)
             .HasColumnName("AddBy");
```

Model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TEEPOEEApp.Models
{
    public partial class Eng_Designation_Name
    {
        public Eng_Designation_Name()
        {
            Eng_DownTimeDay_Designation_Name = new HashSet<Eng_DownTimeDay_Designation_Name>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Designation_Names_Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Designation_Names { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250)]
        public string AddBy { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Designation_Names")]
        public virtual ICollection<Eng_DownTimeDay_Designation_Name> Eng_DownTimeDay_Designation_Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TEEPOEEApp.Models;

namespace TEEPOEEApp.Controllers
{
    public class Eng_Designation_Name : Controller
    {
        private readonly TEEPOEEAppDBContext _context;

        public Eng_Designation_Name(TEEPOEEAppDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Eng_Designation_Name
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Eng_Designation_Name.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Eng_Designation_Name/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Eng_Designation_Name == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var eng_Designation_Name = await _context.Eng_Designation_Name
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Designation_Names_Id == id);

            if (eng_Designation_Name == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(eng_Designation_Name);
        }

        // GET: Eng_Designation_Name/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Eng_Designation_Name/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Designation_Names_Id,Designation_Names,AddBy,AddDate")] Eng_Designation_Name eng_Designation_Name)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                eng_Designation_Name.AddDate = DateTime.Now;
                eng_Designation_Name.AddBy = User.Identity.Name;

                _context.Add(eng_Designation_Name);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(eng_Designation_Name);
        }

        // GET: Eng_Designation_Name/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Eng_Designation_Name == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var eng_Designation_Name = await _context.Eng_Designation_Name.FindAsync(id);

            if (eng_Designation_Name == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(eng_Designation_Name);
        }

        // POST: Eng_Designation_Name/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Designation_Names_Id,Designation_Names,AddBy,AddDate")] Eng_Designation_Name eng_Designation_Name)
        {
            if (id != eng_Designation_Name.Designation_Names_Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    eng_Designation_Name.AddDate = DateTime.Now;
                    eng_Designation_Name.AddBy = User.Identity.Name + "   Edit";

                    _context.Update(eng_Designation_Name);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!Eng_Designation_NameExists(eng_Designation_Name.Designation_Names_Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(eng_Designation_Name);
        }

        // GET: Eng_Designation_Name/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Eng_Designation_Name == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var eng_Designation_Name = await _context.Eng_Designation_Name
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Designation_Names_Id == id);

            if (eng_Designation_Name == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(eng_Designation_Name);
        }

        // POST: Eng_Designation_Name/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Eng_Designation_Name == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'TEEPOEEAppDBContext.Eng_Designation_Names'  is null.");
            }

            var eng_Designation_Name = await _context.Eng_Designation_Name.FindAsync(id);

            if (eng_Designation_Name != null)
            {
                _context.Eng_Designation_Name.Remove(eng_Designation_Name);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool Eng_Designation_NameExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Eng_Designation_Name.Any(e => e.Designation_Names_Id == id);
        }

        // POST: Eng_Designation_Name/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Designation_Names_Id,Designation_Names,AddBy,AddDate")] Eng_Designation_Name eng_Designation_Name)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                eng_Designation_Name.AddDate = DateTime.Now;
                eng_Designation_Name.AddBy = User.Identity.Name;

                _context.Add(eng_Designation_Name);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(eng_Designation_Name);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add another table on the model and run the app, but I got the following errors:

> Error CS1061
> 'Eng_Designation_Name' does not contain a definition for 'AddDate' and no accessible extension method 'AddDate' accepting a first argument of type 'Eng_Designation_Name' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    TEEPOEEApp  C:\Users\londono-ecr\source\repos\TEEPOEEApp\TEEPOEEApp\Controllers\Eng_Designation_NameController.cs   65  Active
>
> Error CS1061
> 'Eng_Designation_Name' does not contain a definition for 'AddBy' and no accessible extension method 'AddBy' accepting a first argument of type 'Eng_Designation_Name' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    TEEPOEEApp  C:\Users\londono-ecr\source\repos\TEEPOEEApp\TEEPOEEApp\Controllers\Eng_Designation_NameController.cs   66  Active

I don't understand very well what is the reason.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the column name for AddDate in this line in your DbContext class:

```
entity.Property(e => e.AddDate)
              .HasColumnType("datetime")
              .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your **Controller** and your **Model** classes have the **same name** `Eng_Designation_Name`. This causes confusion in the code.

---

Either use two different names.

For example, specifically add "Controller" to the name of the Controller class:

```
namespace TEEPOEEApp.Controllers
{
    public class Eng_Designation_Name_Controller : Controller
```

Note that it is generally a convention in .net ASP MVC that the name of a Controller class should end with "Controller".

Also note that in c#, as a convention, we generally don't use underscores within identifiers. This will not cause errors, but might lead to unhappy faces when experienced C# developers have to work with the code.

---

Or specify the full namespace for the type when using it and there can be misunderstandings.

For example here:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create
    ([Bind("Designation_Names_Id,Designation_Names,AddBy,AddDate")]
    Eng_Designation_Name eng_Designation_Name)
```

The compiler understands `Eng_Designation_Name` to mean the Controller class with that name, not the Model. Use the full namespace for the type to make clear you mean the Model:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create
    ([Bind("Designation_Names_Id,Designation_Names,AddBy,AddDate")]
    TEEPOEEApp.Models.Eng_Designation_Name eng_Designation_Name)
```